# Extend Map.set to save the new entry also on the disk

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, persistence

This is not for production just for developing purpose to start from where I left of when I restart the local server.

I try not to modify the production code for this. I want to save to disk the new entry when calling `map.set(...)`. The code bellow to get an idea what I want.

```
// developing code that will be commented out in production
Map.prototype.set=()=>{
  // new functionality save to disk with something like fs.writeFileSync()
  return new Map.set() // keep the original functionality
}

// production code
const map = new Map().set('a',1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not mistaken:

```js
'use strict';

const oldSet = Map.prototype.set;

Map.prototype.set = function (key, value) {
  console.log(key, value); // or other IO actions
  oldSet.call(this, key, value);
};

const map = new Map();
map.set('a', 1);

console.log(map.get('a'));
```

But maybe this would be a safer way:

```js
'use strict';

class fsMap extends Map {
  set(key, value) {
    console.log(key, value); // or other IO actions
    super.set(key, value);
  }
}

const map = new fsMap();
map.set('a', 1);

console.log(map.get('a'));
```

Comment: If I have `map1=new Map(); map2=new Map()` is it possible to get in the same evil way the name of the variables `map1`  and `map2` in the extended Map.set ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand correctly. Can you elaborate or provide a wider example?

Comment: `Map.prototype.set = (key, value) => {console.log(arguments.callee.caller.name, key, value); return oldSet.call(this, key, value);}` , notice `arguments.callee.caller.name` trying to get if `map1` or `map2` is using `.set()` I am in node.js enviroment

Comment: `arguments.callee.caller.name` gives you the name of the function, from which `.set()` was called, like `foo` in `(function foo() { map.set('a', 1); })();`. While `map1` is not the name of a function, it is the name of an object, instance of the `Map` class. I am afraid I do not know a way to get such name if there is any. BTW, you cannot use arrow function as a method, it has not proper `this` binding.